# How to append only node's child nodes?

Tags: javascript, html

Assuming the following node(s) (which is/are actually not generated like this):

```
let outer = document.createElement('div');
outer.innerHTML = `
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>bar</div>
  .
  .
  .
  <div>whatever</div>
`;
```

Now I can append `outer` to another node:

```
let body = document.querySelector('body');
body.append(outer);
```

But how to append only the inner of `outer` without loosing event listeners etc.?

Comment: Delegate from the nearest static container - in this case body

Comment: Please  post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: If you are concerned about preserving event handlers, then you should see how [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) is done.

Comment: "_without loosing event listeners_": I don't see any event listeners in the details of your question.

Comment: @mplungjan How do you mean "delegate from the nearest static container"?

Comment: @zer00ne That doesn't answer my question, but thank you anyway.

Comment: @jsejcksn I left them out in my simple example for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: If you have event listeners, move them to the body. `body.addEventListener("click", function(e) { const tgt = e.target; if (tgt.matches(".divClass1")) .... })`

Comment: @mplungjan Ah, I see! Unfortunately not an option here.

Comment: However it seems they are NOT lost when appended, so never mind my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `append()` with each child of `outer` as a separate argument by using the `...` syntax to spread an iterable.

```
body.append(...outer.children);
```

Comment: Why not use the more compact ES6 syntax?

Comment: I figured there was an easier/more intuitive way. Thank you!

Comment: Just iterate the `HTMLCollection` directly with a `for...of` loop: `for (const child of outer.children) { body.append(child); }`

Comment: @jsejcksn That won't work because appending the node somewhere else will take it out of the `children` list.

Comment: @trincot I just came up with something better.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, I see... because it's live. :/

Comment: @Barmar Great. Just one closing parenthesis too many.

Comment: @jsejcksn "because it's live. :/" What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Fred When you append a child to another node, it's immediately removed from the children of `outer`. If you try to iterate over `outer.children` directly, indexes change as you're going and the iteration will skip elements.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your "without losing event handlers" - it turns out your are not when you append

Without delegation

```js
let outer = document.createElement('div');
outer.classList.add("outer")
outer.innerHTML = `
  <div class="foo" onclick="console.log('Foo clicked')">foo</div>
  <div class="bar">bar</div>
  <div>whatever</div>
`;

let body = document.querySelector('body');
body.append(outer);
body.append(...outer.children);
```

```css
.outer { height:100px; width:100px; border: 1px solid red;}
```

With delegation from body

```js
let outer = document.createElement('div');
outer.classList.add("outer")
outer.innerHTML = `
  <div class="foo">foo</div>
  <div class="bar">bar</div>
  <div>whatever</div>
`;

let body = document.querySelector('body');
body.append(outer);
body.append(...outer.children);
body.addEventListener("click", e => {  
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches(".foo")) console.log("Foo clicked")
  else if (tgt.matches(".bar")) console.log("Bar clicked")
})
```

```css
.outer { height:100px; width:100px; border: 1px solid red;}
```